# Convert pulsar data to sound

Tags: data-analysis, pulsar, sound

I have a filterbank data (say name.fil) which I have dedispersed and stored into name.dat file using PRESTO. May I ask for detailed steps and explanation on how to convert that data to sound?

Comment: There might or might not be a "standard procedure" for this, and options may involve some creative license and depend on the detailed nature of your data. Are there any details you can add, like the number of bands in your filter bank, the time spacing, total length, etc for example?

Comment: And just fyi there exists [Signal Processing SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) though I think think it's best to start here in Astronomy SE first where people will have a better appreciation of what aspects of pulsars might be important to keep. I think it's going to be difficult if the number of frequencies per octave is not very high because a naive reconstruction will just sound like individual tones unless you do something creative.